# Sending log4j logs to logstash with java

Tags: java, log4j, logstash

Is there any way to send log4j logs from java program to logstash ?

Thanks in advance for any help that you might be able to provide.

Comment: Googling "logstash log4j" would've given you an answer, but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29487414/logstash-shipper-configuration-for-jira/.

Comment: Or look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26728273/logstash-with-log4j-socketappender-doesnt-work/26858968#26858968